# Cómo utilizar orWhere en una colección

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$movements = Movement::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
$expenses = $movements->orWhere('currency', 'Dólar')->orWhere('currency', 'euro')->sum('expense');
```

Ya que podría ser alguno de los dos valores, Dólar o Euro, pero me da el siguiente error:

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orwhere does not exist.

Comment: Es que ahí en `$movements` tenés una colección, y las colecciones no tienen ese método. Necesitas los otros registros que tenés en $movements para algo más, o sólo haces la consulta para obtener la suma?

Comment: Vas a motrar los resultados paginados y a parte la suma o toda la consulta es sola para la sumatoria?, por favor explica mejor que deseas lograr

Comment: Fuera de tema, porque no conozco la lógica del negocio, pero también está raro que quieras sumar dólar con euro, pues usualmente se suma dólar con dólar y euro con euro.

Comment: Debería ser un único `where` que reciba un valor dinámico y en función de eso entregue el resultado o si quieres ambos entonces mejor usa un `CASE`, en cualquier caso sería mejor conocer bien lo que planeas obtener

Comment: Sé que así `$total_badge_expenses = Movement::orwhere('currency', 'Dólar')->orwhere('currency', 'euro')->sum('expense');` la obtengo completa, pero también se me ocurrió mostrar un total por cada página (Paginación) por eso la duda.

Comment: @ porloscerros Ψ aquí en Venezuela las cosas no son igual que otros paises :), acá están recibiendo el Dólar a la par con el Euro 1 a 1, por esa razón sería indiferente, pero si se requiere diferenciar entre cada uno para el cuadre de caja. Gracias!

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces puedes usar un `whereIn` en vez de dos `orWhere` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein

Comment: Perfecto, era lo que necesitaba!

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ considera responderla y así no queda abierta la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como en `$movements` tienes una colección, y las colecciones no tienen ese método (puedes ver todos lo métodos disponibles para una colección [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)), una alternativa puede ser usando el método

#### [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein)

> El método `whereIn` filtra la colección por una clave/valor dada contenida en el array dado.

Para tu caso:

```
$expenses = $movements->whereIn('currency', ['Dólar', 'euro'])->sum('expense');
```